# How do I convert one item of a list into a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

So, imagine I have a list Things:

```
things = ['bananas', 'oranges', 'apples']
```

And I want to convert item 2 (index 1) into a string to store it into another variable.

When I try to just print it out, I get this:

```
['oranges']
```

I want this to be a string instead of an item in a list.

I've tried the str() function, but Python spits out a TypeError. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Here's the context:

```
def whileremove(x):
    while(x in scriptlines):
        new_r = scriptlines[x]
        new_r = new_r.replace(x, "")
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something contrary to my original question, but new_r.replace doesn't treat new_r as a string.

Comment: `things[1]` returns `'oranges'`, which is a string

Comment: What is 'x' passed to the function whileremove meant to be?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing things[1] is itself returns a string you don't have to change this to string.`print(things[1])` you will eventually get 'oranges'.

Answer (score 0):

This should be relatively straight forward. To access the second element you can use:

```
things[1]
```

This will return the string 'oranges'.

To confirm this you can do the following:

```
things = ['bananas', 'oranges', 'apples']
orange_string = things[1]
print(type(orange_string))
```

Which will return:

```
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
things = ['bananas', 'oranges', 'apples'] 
othervariable = str(things[1])
```

In [7]: type(othervariable)
Out[7]: str

In [8]: othervariable
Out[8]: 'oranges'

???

Answer (score 0):

While converting a list to a string, accessing its elements will eventually return a String.

```
things = ['bananas', 'oranges', 'apples']
```

Here, things[1] will return 'oranges'
To confirm the return type, just type(things[1]), this results in <class 'str'>